# Dynamically change css value with Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Seems real simple but I think I am missing something.

Let's say I want the following code but I don't want the "12px" to be static.I  want to use the variable `fontInput`. How would I rewrite this?

```
 var fontInput = document.getElementById("changesize").value; 

     $('.schedule-show').css({"font-size":"12px"});
```

Comment: why not just use fontInput instead of "12px"?

Comment: `{"font-size":fontInput})`

Comment: Doing so breaks the code .. it doesn't seem to accept fontInput: 
$('.schedule-show').css({"font-size":fontInput)});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work better, supposing #changesize is expecting a number:

```
var fontInput = document.getElementById("changesize").value; 
$('.schedule-show').css({"font-size": fontInput + "px"});
```

That way you concatenate the number from the user input into a valid string for the font-size CSS rule.

Comment: that was the answer. proper concatenation. Thank you

Comment: I'm glad it works! Could you mark this as the answer?